# Errors with fx and Application

Tags: java, javafx, extends

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

public class LoanCalculator extends Application
{
    public void start(Stage myStage)
    {
        myStage.setTitle("Loan Calculator");
        FlowPlane rootNode = new FlowPane();
        Scene myScene = new Scene( rootNode, 300, 200 );
        myStage.setScene( myScene);
        myStage.show();     
    }

    public static void main( String [] args)
    {
        launch(args);

    }

}
```

This code pops up with multiply errors when I try running it with Eclipse. I apologize if it is an obvious error. I am new to coding, I found this piece of code in my book and I wanted to test it out.

Thanks Guys

Comment: What errors show up?

Comment: The first error says that "Application is not API"

Comment: It basically says everything is not API

Comment: which version of java, you are using JDK 8 ?

Comment: Yes update the JDK 7 to update 6 or later..before this Java FX was not supported by JDK, you had to install separate Java FX SDK to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is ir just a typo? In your code it reads: FlowPlane instead of FlowPane.

Answer (score 0):

Java FX is supported by JDK starting from JDK 7 update 6.
Updated my JDK 7 update 5 to JDK 8, executed your code, it worked like a magic.
Also correct the FlowPlane to FlowPane as suggested below by Kornel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated to JDK 8 and the program runs now but for some reason it still displays many errors. I think it might have something to do with javafx.